# What is the Applescript command to show or hide iTerm2 window

Tags: applescript, iterm

Does anybody know the Applescript command to show or hide a iTerm2 terminal window? I use iTerm2 in a guake style command window and currently using one window and many tabs.

My use case: I managed to open a new iTerm2 tab from Forklift (see [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/binarynights/topics/how_can_i_change_the_program_opened_with_the_open_in_terminal_with_iterm2_or_other#reply_7754288)) but I still need to activate iTerm2 manually with my show/hide shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried every of this solution. None if them worked as expected. They all opened a completely new terminal or did not worked. The only solution which worked for me in the full screen iTerm Hotkey Window was to simulate keypresses.

Be sure to disable `Hotkey toggles a dedicated window with profile` in settings or you need to simulate even that hotkey press which caused the major pain for my problem.

[image]

Here is the file `/Applications/ForkLift.app/Contents/Resources/OpenInTerminal.applescript` which:

- opens my fullscreen terminal app, opens a new session window (my session is named `Hot`, change it to `Default` or your desired session type from profiles)
- waits for 1 second (otherwise the new session is not recognized)
- changes the directory and clears screen

---

```
tell application "iTerm"
    activate

    try
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down
        delay 1
        set _session to current session of current terminal
    on error
        set _term to (make new terminal)
        tell _term
            launch session "Hot"
            set _session to current session
        end tell
    end try

    tell _session
        write text "cd _forklift_path_placeholder_;clear;"
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 16):

Here are several options (none of them have been tested, so test and see which one works for you):

### Option 1:

```
tell application "iTerm2" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTerm2" to keystroke "h" using command down
```

Note: Keystroke may be replaced with *m* if you want iTerm2 to be *minimized* to the dock with the Genie effect.

### Option 2:

```
tell application "Finder"
set visible of process "iTerm2" to false
end tell
```

### Option 3:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTerm2" to set visible to false
```

Note: The process name may just be **iTerm** instead of iTerm2. I opened iTerm on my Mac and then `Activity Monitor`, and the `Process Name` that it shows is `iTerm`. Please change accordingly if it does not work for you.

### Links and Resources

Here is a great [WikiBooks link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AppleScript_Programming/Advanced_Code_List/Hide_Application) that describes exactly what you need.

Please let me know which option works for you so I can edit the question and only include the option that works.

### Edit:

If you make the iTerm window the frontmost application (Be careful you don't want to make the AppleScript window the frontmost application), try this script:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontProcess to first process whose frontmost is true
    set visible of frontProcess to false
end tell
```

Comment: tested both. Both do not work. iTerm2 is activated but the terminal window only shows after pressing the shortcut key. Thanks for the try.

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?

Answer (score 4):

```
tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where frontmost is true)
    if name is "iTerm" then
        set visible to false
        return
    end if
end tell
tell application "iTerm"
    reopen -- open a default window if there are no open windows
    activate -- make frontmost
end tell
```

If others were looking for a way to show or hide iTerm in general, you can set a shortcut for it in the preferences or use Alfred:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

`tell application "iTerm2" to activate
    set miniaturized of window 1 to true
end tell`

http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=12501

the wording of your question makes me think you want individual windows out of the way. The hide function on mac will hide everything. I needed a window away from view. the url above was helpful.

your solution may not be hiding a single window but rather minimizing a single window.